# PyTorch ValueError: Expected target size (2, 33), got torch.Size([2, 73])

Tags: python, pytorch, loss-function, valueerror, cross-entropy

I'm quite new to Pytorch.
I want to compute the loss of a batch in a Transformer. In this case my 'batch' has only two replicas.
The batch outputs a Tensor of the shape 2,73,33:

```
output
tensor([[[ 21.1355,  -7.5047,   2.8138,  ..., -14.1462, -15.1999,  -7.2595],...
output.size()
>>> torch.Size([2, 73, 33])
```

The target has the categorical solution for each position. It has the shape 2,73:

```
target.size()
>>> torch.Size([2, 73])
```

When I compute the loss, I get a value in the case I only compare the first replica:

```
loss = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss(ignore_index=1)
loss(output[0], target[0])
tensor(0.1967)
```

But it errors when I do it all at once:

```
loss = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss(ignore_index=1)
loss(output, target)
ValueError: Expected target size (2, 33), got torch.Size([2, 73])
```

Do I have to loop over the replicas and average them?
Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Why do you output 73x33 when you have a 73x1 target? When you want to get rid of the 33 (third dim of your output) maybe try ```ignore_index=2```

Comment: ignore_index refers to the indices to ignore in the target (because the inputs have different lengths, they are padded to the same length using a padding token (which is in this case the number 1)